# How to add a (fake) callable parameter to my PyTorch model?

Tags: python, parameters, pytorch

I know that the code below would add `torch.tensor([0.], requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float64)` as a parameter to `myPyTorchModel`:

```py
myPyTorchModel = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([0.], 
                                    requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float64))
```

However, `torch.tensor([0.], requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float64)` is not a callable parameter.

Is there any way that I can manually add a (fake) callable parameter to `myPyTorchModel`?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to make it callable, you can use `lambda`:

```
>>> myPyTorchModel = lambda: torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([0.], 
                                    requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float64))
>>> myPyTorchModel()
```